# How can I declare a list in separate line

Tags: vb.net

I want following code in two lines.

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35})
```

I have tried following codes but it doesnt work.

Could you please repair following code?

```
    Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
    MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    myList = (New Integer() {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35})
```

So, how can I declare a list in separate line?

Comment: Why the C#-tag? Anyway from my memories you need a `_` to introduce a line-break in VB.

Comment: Do you want to add them to the existing list or create a new list and assign that to the existing variable?

Comment: @HimBromBeere That is no longer the case, since Visual Studio 2017, so you can free up that memory space :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
Dim myList As New List(Of Integer)
myList.AddRange({30, 31, 32, 33, 34 , 35})
```

Or

```
Dim myList As List(Of Integer)
MessageBox.Show("Hello") 
myList = New List(Of Integer) From {30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35}
```